# Need to initialize empty list within recursive function only once on the first call. if conditioning on a depth variable doesn't work

Tags: python, recursion, flags, depth

I tried below piece of code:

```
def split(arr,i=0):

    if i==0:
        print("hey")
        splitted=[]
        print('splitted initialized')


    a1=arr[:len(arr)//2]
    a2=arr[len(arr)//2:]
    if len(a1)>2:
        print("splitting "+str(a1))
        i+=1
        split(a1,i)
    else:
        print("not splitting "+str(a1))
        splitted.append(a1)

    if len(a2)>2:
        print("splitting "+str(a2))
        i+=1
        split(a2,i)
    else:
        print("not splitting "+str(a2))
        splitted.append(a2)

    return(splitted)
```

I am getting the below error when I execute:

split([1,2,3,4,6,7,8,54,76,3,4,5,67,78,8,7,45,2])
I expected the empty list "splitted" to be initializes only once during 0th initialization

```
hey
splitted initialized
splitting [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 54, 76]
splitting [1, 2, 3, 4]
not splitting [1, 2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#37>", line 1, in <module>
    split([1,2,3,4,6,7,8,54,76,3,4,5,67,78,8,7,45,2])
  File "\Documents\python_projects-20170821\python_projects\sorting_algorithms\merge_sort\merge_sort.py", line 15, in split
    split(a1,i)
  File "\Documents\python_projects-20170821\python_projects\sorting_algorithms\merge_sort\merge_sort.py", line 15, in split
    split(a1,i)
  File "\Documents\python_projects-20170821\python_projects\sorting_algorithms\merge_sort\merge_sort.py", line 18, in split
    splitted.append(a1)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'splitted' referenced before assignment
```

I am able to overcome by nesting the this function within another function as shown below:

below code works fine on calling:
splitter([1,2,3,4,6,7,8,54,76,3,4,5,67,78,8,7,45,2])

```
def splitter(arr):
    splitted=[]
    def split(arr):
        a1=arr[:len(arr)//2]
        a2=arr[len(arr)//2:]
        if len(a1)>2:
            print("splitting "+str(a1))

            split(a1)
        else:
            print("not splitting "+str(a1))
            splitted.append(a1)

        if len(a2)>2:
            print("splitting "+str(a2))

            split(a2)
        else:
            print("not splitting "+str(a2))
            splitted.append(a2)

        return(splitted)
    return split(arr)
```

I just want to understand why my first version of code dosen't work?

Comment: In the recursive cases, `i` is greater than zero and so `split()` will not **define** `splitted` and so you get your error.

Comment: Actually your nested function solution is a brilliant piece of python design!

Comment: hi @quamrana but in output you can see hey
splitted initialized

Comment: @SudhanNadar yes that is correct for the base case `i=0` not for every other case in the recursive call

Comment: Just because in one call to `split` it defines `splitted`, does not mean that all recursive calls can see `splitted`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version of `split` might work (But I like your nested function better)

```
def split(arr, splitted=None):

    if splitted == None:
        print("hey")
        splitted = []
        print('splitted initialized')

    a1=arr[:len(arr)//2]
    a2=arr[len(arr)//2:]
    if len(a1)>2:
        print("splitting "+str(a1))
        split(a1, splitted)

    # the reset elided
```

Note how `splitted` is passed down the chain of recursion.

Comment: Agreed. just curious what happens to the variable splitted.

Comment: It may be local to that one instance of function call.

Comment: I always dodged these issues in most practical problems but it nags me what if i want to make a decision based based on depth of recursion.

Comment: You just need to do some research on recursive functions to find out how parameters are handled.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you only define splitted when i is greater than zero. You could try

```
def split(arr,splitted=None):

    if splitted is None:
        print("hey")
        splitted=[]
        print('splitted initialized')
```

and then, when you call your function, you pass the splitted list instead of the parameter i.

Comment: splitted is defined when i is equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
def split(arr,res,i=0):

    if i==0:
        print("hey")
        print('splitted initialized')


    a1=arr[:len(arr)//2]
    a2=arr[len(arr)//2:]
    if len(a1)>2:
        print("splitting "+str(a1))
        i+=1
        split(a1,res,i)
    else:
        print("not splitting "+str(a1))
        res.append(a1)

    if len(a2)>2:
        print("splitting "+str(a2))
        i+=1
        split(a2,res,i)
    else:
        print("not splitting "+str(a2))
        res.append(a2)

    return
```

Then the output becomes

```
a=list()
split([1,2,3,4,6,7,8,54,76,3,4,5,67,78,8,7,45,2],a)
print(a)
```

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

Comment: Also, every time in main after the first call to `split` you will have to manually reset the result using `splitted = []`

Comment: Sure, but since this is DFS, why do we need to reset the result?

Comment: Please tell me what `DFS` is?

Comment: My bad. I meant "depth-first-search". When we are recursing in depth-first mechanism, we will always get the left most entry in the list and they would be appended to the result array, right?

Comment: When I mentioned the manual reset, I was referring to calls to `split` outside the `split` function itself, not its own recursive calls.

Comment: Yes. As you said, using the global variables could cause many problems in debugging and finding bugs. So it would be better to pass the reference of the local variable. I have edited the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to attack the problem. We start with a helper, `cut_at_index` which takes a list, an index `i`, and lambda which will receive the `left` and `right` result of the "cut"

Now let's plan how we will write the recursive `split` function

- the **base** case is `len(ls) < 3:` where we return a singleton list of the unmodified input
- the **inductive** case is length is *not* less than 3 (ie `>= 3`), therefore we have an array big enough to cut. We call our `cut_at_index` which gives us new `left` and `right` pieces in our lambda. We then call `split` on each piece and simply merge (`+`) the result together

As a result of this implementation, pain and suffering are removed from the program

```
def cut_at_index (ls, i = 0, k = lambda left, right: (left, right)):
  return k (ls[:i], ls[i:])

def split (ls):
  if len (ls) < 3:
    return [ ls ]
  else:
    return cut_at_index (ls, len (ls) // 2, lambda left, right:
      split (left) + split (right))

print (split ([ 1 ]))
print (split ([ 1, 2 ]))
print (split ([ 1, 2, 4 ]))
print (split ([ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]))
print (split ([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]))
print (split ([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]))
print (split ([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8 ]))
print (split ([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 ]))
print (split ([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10 ]))
print (split ([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11 ]))
print (split ([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ]))
# [[1]]
# [[1, 2]]
# [[1], [2, 4]]
# [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
# [[1, 2], [3], [4, 5]]
# [[1], [2, 3], [4], [5, 6]]
# [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 8]]
# [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [8, 9]]
# [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [8], [9, 10]]
# [[1, 2], [3], [4, 5], [6, 8], [9], [10, 11]]
# [[1, 2], [3], [4, 5], [6], [8, 9], [10], [11, 12]]
```

Because `cut_at_index`'s continuation parameter `k` has a default value, we can also use it in direct style with destructuring assignment (instead of continuation passing style). Program readability is improved as a result.

```
def split (ls):
  if len (ls) < 3:
    return [ ls ]
  else:
    (left, right) = cut_at_index (ls, len (ls) // 2)
    return split (left) + split (right)

print (split ([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ]))
# [[1, 2], [3], [4, 5], [6], [8, 9], [10], [11, 12]]
```